# registering all callbacks before using them

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 vue components that I want to communicate with each other. This is the timeline I want:

- `ComponentA`: add callback to `EventB` - prints `action complete`
- `ComponentB`: add callback to `EventA` - does action and when complete, emits `EventB`
- `ComponentA`: emits `EventA`

however what appears to be happening:

- `ComponentA`: add callback to `EventB` - prints `action complete`
- `ComponentA`: emits `EventA`
- `ComponentB`: add callback to `EventA` - does action and when complete, emits `EventB`

as a result, `ComponentB` never receives `EventA` so the action never happens.

---

I have tried adding both the callback registrations to the `v-on:beforeCreate` event on the respective components and then added the emitting of `EventA` to `v-on:created` - but it doesn't fix the problem.

I am registering to events using `this.$root.$on(...)` and `this.$root.$emit(...)`

Comment: Are you talking about the order of actions? And did you try using `Promise`s?

Comment: @YomS. yes that is the order of actions I want, no I am not using Promises

Comment: the action must be done on `ComponentB` and then `ComponentA` must know about it once complete